# Server error when trying to report Achievement to GameCenter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, game-center

When using the code from Apple,

```
- (void) reportAchievementIdentifier: (NSString*) identifier percentComplete: (float) percent
{
    GKAchievement *achievement = [[[GKAchievement alloc] initWithIdentifier: identifier] autorelease];
    if (achievement)
    {
  achievement.percentComplete = percent;
  [achievement reportAchievementWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error)
   {
    if (error != nil)
    {
     NSLog(@"problem with reporting");
     NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
     // Retain the achievement object and try again later (not shown).
    }
   }];
    }
}
```

I  get the error:

> The requested operation could not be completed due to an error communicating with the server.

I have verified the user and it seems to register that i have played the game, but it cannot record the achievement.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the reachability sample application from Apple to find out if the iPhone is connected to the internet via wifi or 3G. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Hi thanks, I am connected to the internet, in fact, if i use this authentication command from the apple i am authenticated player- (void) authenticateLocalPlayer
{
    [[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
  if (error == nil)
  {
   NSLog(@"The player has been authenticated");
   
   // Insert code here to handle a successful authentication.
  }
  else
  {
   NSLog(@"The player hasn't been authenticated");
   // Your application can process the error parameter to report the error to the player.
  }
 }];
}

Comment: I don't see anything there. Hmmm. Perhaps the achievement gets autoreleased before the handler can recieve the callback? Perhaps try to retain it instead?

Answer (score 0):

It takes a few minutes for the Achievements from itunesconnect to propagate to the server.
Just try a little later, and it will not hurt to deinstall and install app again either.